# Cannot access some websites using dlink wireless router

Tags: internet, ubuntu-12.10

I recently bought a dlink wireless router from orange that also have an option for ethernet connection. am using an Evdo modem for internet and the modem works fine when connected directly to the machine. The wireless and the ethernet connection works well on windows os but apparently i cannot access some website when connected to ubuntu.

I have changed my default dns to opendns and also tried playing around with MTU currently at 1492, ipv6 settings are set to ignore, the problem is still persistent.

the dlink router is a DIR 412,

Is there any other settings that am missing,

Edit
Some of those sites that wont connect are google youtube and gmail

Edit

```
/etc/resolv.conf is
  Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
 nameserver 212.49.70.22
 nameserver 212.49.70.23
```

Comment: What country are you in? Also, is it just sites on the google network? Google Youtube and gmail will all be loading in similar ways. Try Lifehacker, Engadget etc. Tell me if you can access them. Your country may have a firewall.

Comment: What's the Ubuntu /etc/resolv.conf look like?

Comment: am in kenya, am not sure if we have a firewall here coz the evdo modem works with those sites when connected directly,and windows also works well when connected to the dlink connection, i will try the sites suggested and give a feed back

Comment: my ubuntu /etc/resolv.conf is # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 212.49.70.22
nameserver 212.49.70.23

Comment: i can access Engadget and lifehacker. sites on the google network seems not to work

Comment: The router is configured with DHCP? Can you ping router's IP? Can you ping DNS servers? Check /var/log/syslog for connection error messages.